# A right way to convert a string into std::vector<int>

Tags: c++

What is a right way to convert a `std::string` containing comma-separated numbers without spaces:

```
123,45,6,78,88,94
```

into `std::vector<int>`?

EDIT1:

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
std::string s = "123,45,6,78,88,94";
std::istringstream in(s);
std::vector<int> v;
in >> v;
```

Comment: I would suggest converting the individual numbers and then pushing them into the vector? What do you think?

Comment: @Quimby see EDIT1, is it possible?

Comment: you're gonna need to call `atoi` or `stoi` somewhere at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be fancy you can use range-v3 (or a `std::ranges` implementation supporting `ranges::to`):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <range/v3/view.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string s = "123,45,6,78,88,94";
    auto v = s | 
             ranges::views::split(',') |
             ranges::views::transform([](auto num) {
                 return std::strtol(&*ranges::begin(num), nullptr, 10);
             }) | 
             ranges::to<std::vector<int>>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can split the string, then convert each of them to an integer:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    std::stringstream test("123,45,6,78,88,94");
    std::string segment;
    std::vector<int> result;

    // Split the string, convert to an integer, push to result vector
    while(std::getline(test, segment, ','))
    {
        result.push_back(std::stoi(segment));
    }

    // result contains what we want
    for (int i: result){
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    // outputs 123 45 6 78 88 94 
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `seglist` intermediary. Why don't you directly push into the vector ?

Comment: @Fareanor well spotted ! I'm updating the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::istringstream` and `std::getline` with `','` as separator to get each number as a separate string, then convert each string to an integer, then add the integer to the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you tokenize the input and then transform it into `int`s which are inserted at the back of the destination container. :)

```
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include<algorithm>  // for std::transform
#include<string>


int main() {
    std::string const s = "123,45,6,78,88,94";
    boost::tokenizer const tk{s};

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(s.size()/3);  // estimate based on expected number of digits of each element

    std::transform(tk.begin(), tk.end(), std::back_inserter(v), [](auto const& e) {return std::stoi(e);});

    assert( v[2] == 6 );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ejfxf77f6

Comment: it is also probably `std::ranges::split_view'

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, I am an STL-classic guy still.

Answer (score 2):

Another way :

```
std::vector<int> integers(std::count(your_string.begin(), your_string.end(), ',') + 1);
{
    std::string x;
    std::istringstream iss(your_string);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; std::getline(str, x, ','); ++i)
        std::istringstream(x) >> integers[i];
}
```